# What can be unique information of a view in android? (Except ID)

Tags: android

I want to store **View** information so that I can later use it for purpose of identifying it.

Comment: What is wrong with id?

Comment: You can Use IMEI also

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly what R.ID is for, but if you insist that you don't want it, you can use tags. However you have to make sure they're unique yourself

Comment: @PavanBirajdar if my answer answers your question, accepting it is the way to thank me :)